# Can I use Whenever Gem with a Module Method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I've created a very small application in rails where I've created a module method in /lib to handle the logic.

I've also set up Whenever to run that Module Method at set times. I've followed both the [readme from Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/README.md) and these [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548730/cron-job-not-working-in-whenever-gem/13257752#13257752) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831603/unable-to-run-cronjob-using-whenever-in-rails-3) to hopefully set things up correctly.

When looking at the readme though the examples are quoted like this:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end

every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  runner "SomeModel.ladeeda"
end
```

My question therefore is does whenever have to reference a method in the model? or can it reference a module method in /lib? [Looking at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305767/rails-whenever-gem-how-to-run-specific-method-in-controller-rb-file) it seems to allude to having to have the method in the model.

My problem is that I don't have a database and so no models.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can reference a method in any class or or any module.  (A module is just a class that can't instantiate).

If there's some intermediate data that you need to pass between methods in your module, it sometimes helps to make the module a PORO (plain old Ruby object) class, which lets you instantiate (i.e. use the `new` and `initialize` methods) and you can store values in `attr_accessor` attributes available to all instance methods for that object.

Comment: hi @SteveTurczyn thanks for your answer. it clarifies things a little better for me. I've put a description in @Uzbekjon answer, as to what I was doing wrong, and why I was confused by the Readme syntax for Whenever. Basically `MyModel` in `runner "MyModel.some_process"` totally threw me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call methods on models only. As far as a class/module is available/accessible in your current scope, you can call it. Since `runner` can access models, probably you have setup the whenever gem to load rails app as well. It means that it can also access any classes/modules in your `/lib` folder as well.

So, go ahead and call then in your whenever:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "YourModule.some_method"
end
```

If you are not using any Rails specific features, I would suggest not to load Rails env. You would save significant resources and it will perform faster.

Alternatively, create a `rake` task that does the processing and invoke that instead. As a benefit, you would end up with a rake task you can call and test yourself.

```
every 3.hours do
  rake "cron:my_process"
end
```

Comment: Hi @Uzbekjon 

Thanks for your answer. To give you more insight, the reason I'd asked that question was because as you can imagine I was trying to call the module method from the route.rb file and it was not working.

In a complete amateur move I hadnt defined the correct way to output the errors from cron. When i did this I was given an error that solved my problem:

`/bin/bash: bundle: command not found`